# C# - Save uploaded Excel file to MemoryStream, then use it to fill a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

I have an ASP.NET website where I am uploading an Excel file and saving it to disk. I am then using OleDbConnection to query the data and fill a DataTable.

Is there a way to accomplish this in memory without first saving the file to disk?

Comment: What version of Excel are you working with?

Comment: Yes, I do need to go back and accept answers on previous questions.

Comment: when you use the @Username the user will be notified of your comment

Answer (score 1):

No affiliation - but this is a great solution: http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/.

You will eventually run into problems working with Excel (and other data sources) with Jet on 64-bit servers. Save yourself all that headache and go with SpreadSheetGear. We did a project with it in the fall and it's been working flawlessly in production for several months.

Answer (score 0):

I make my users export/save as .csv and use [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx).